# How is Double::isFinite different from Double::isInfinite?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, method-reference

I have the following code:

```
class Result {
    public Result(long infiniteCount, DoubleSummaryStatistics statistics) {
        this.infiniteCount = infiniteCount;
        this.statistics = statistics;
    }
    final long infiniteCount;
    final DoubleSummaryStatistics statistics;
}
```

This compiles:

```
Result result = DoubleStream.of(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).boxed().collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.filtering(Double::isFinite, Collectors.counting()),
        Collectors.filtering(Double::isFinite, Collectors.summarizingDouble(d -> d)),
        Result::new));
```

This doesn't:

```
Result result = DoubleStream.of(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).boxed().collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.filtering(Double::isInfinite, Collectors.counting()),
        Collectors.filtering(Double::isFinite, Collectors.summarizingDouble(d -> d)),
        Result::new));
```

Compilation results in this:

> java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s)
> T,A,R,capture#1 of ?,T
> (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
> reference to isInfinite is ambiguous
> both method isInfinite(double) in java.lang.Double and method isInfinite() in java.lang.Double match)

Here is the source code of these 2 methods from Double.java of Java 19... I don't understand why is there difference... (AFAIK `@IntrinsicCandidate` shouldn't affect this, and otherwise it's just two methods that return a boolean).

```
@IntrinsicCandidate
public static boolean isInfinite(double v) {
    return (v == POSITIVE_INFINITY) || (v == NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
}

public static boolean isFinite(double d) {
    return Math.abs(d) <= Double.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

So, why does the first compile and the second doesn't...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the non-static `Double.isInfinite()` method:

```
public boolean isInfinite() {
    return isInfinite(value);
}
```

This makes `Double::isInfinite` ambiguous as both methods match. You could use a lambda to disambiguate it:

```
Collectors.filtering(d -> d.isInfinite(), Collectors.counting())
```

Comment: Thanks. No idea how I didn't see this myself... I guess I had some tunnel vision due to the ridiculous fact that isInfinite has a non-static version and isFinite doesn't...

Answer (score 3):

`isInfinite` exists as static and instance method:

- `static boolean isInfinite(double d)`
- `boolean isInfinite()`

Your method reference becomes ambiguous. By converting to a lambda, you can disambiguate:

```
Result result = DoubleStream.of(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).boxed().collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.filtering(d -> d.isInfinite(), Collectors.counting()),
        Collectors.filtering(Double::isFinite, Collectors.summarizingDouble(d -> d)),
        Result::new));
```